Linking VLD crashes the application
I have a weird problem.
My application contains of an executable and couple of DLLs. The DLLs projects all based on the same template.
I'm linking VLD in order to catch any memory leaks in my software. Trying to load one of the DLLs crashes the program.
As soon as I remove mention of VLD in this DLL - loading it works. There is no issues with any other library.
I double checked and the projects are identical, except the project s called library and its producing the file called library.dll.
Could this be a problem?
Should I raise the issue with the VLD?
